# Require found file, doesn't show String

Tags: php, string, require

First I'm sorry if this question is duplicated but I tried to find here the solution and spent some time reading some tutorials but I haven't found the solution.

I'm starting to learn PHP. I use Easy PHP  13.1 VC9.

In my testing project I have to files:

index.php:

```
<?php
    global $str_texto;
    echo 'before ';
    require ('vars.php');
    echo "$str_texto";
    echo ' after';
?>
```

vars.php:

```
<? php

    global $str_texto = 'String text';
    $data_hoje = date('j / F / Y');

?>
```

When I start index.php my browser shows the page without errors (so I assume that EasyPHP found the file). It shows the words "before" and "after" but doesn't show the $str_texto string.

I compared my code to some code available on web like this available on [PHP: Include - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) :

vars.php

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

test.php

```
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
include 'vars.php';
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

The same problem happens with that sample so, on my code, I changed the Include command to Require so I can get an error message. Same behavior and no error. There's a blank space between "before" and "after" were should be "String text". Declaring $str_texto as global and change quotation marks to single quotes didn't solve the problem.

I wasn't able to find any problem on web like this. Can you help?

Comment: change this echo "$str_texto"; to this echo $str_texto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space in your php declaration in vars.php

```
<? php
```

Should be

```
<?php
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray! Shame on me! I'll put this as the correct answer because it was the first that works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var.php:

```
<?php
global $str_texto;
$str_texto = 'String text';
$data_hoje = date('j / F / Y');
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
global $str_texto;
echo 'before ';
require ('vars.php');
echo $str_texto;
echo ' after';
?>
```

Comment: hi maximus! thanks for your answer! i tried that right now and the page has the same behavior.

Comment: see if the updated answer works. It worked for me on PHP 5.3.13

Comment: It worked maximus! It was only that space. Tiny sintax erros atack again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this without quotes because is a variable:

```
echo $str_texto;
```

AND

change open-tag:

```
<? php
```

to

```
<?php
```

Comment: Thanks a lot aldanux! I can't believe the problem was just a "space". Thanks again!

Comment: This is just the beginning, you will not believe what everything does not work when a little thing is missing! :-) I recommended you to use special software for highlight errors... that help you...[phpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)